# SKU shopping cart rule feature missing?

Tags: magento-1.7, shopping-cart-price-rules

I'd like to explore the SKU shopping cart rule but I don't have it in my options. I see other people used it and pictures of it but it's nowhere on my list. Is there a way I can enable it?

Using: Magento ver. 1.9.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set individual attributes to have the ability to be included in catalogue price rules so one of your installs has different settings at an attribute level.

Go into Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes and for each attribute you want to be able to set a price rule on set Use for Promo Rule Conditions to Yes (its the bottom Front End properties section).

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you can't get to Promotions > Shopping Cart Price Rules in the admin, then your account may not have access to that feature. If there is an administrator that you can talk to, they can put you in another role or change your role to include that feature.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the conditions tab, you must first choose product attribute combination.  Then sku will display under that.